# How to add correct distribution channel for pyculib for windows?

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, cupy

I'm trying to install Nvidia's GPU python packages via conda package distribution, but I'm running into the following errors:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
current channels:

  - pyculib

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

What is the correct distribution channel for CuPy and pyculib packages?

Answer (score 5):

`pyculib` is collected in the `free` channel. But the `free` channel is remove in `conda` 4.7.

[Quote from *Why We Removed the “Free” Channel in Conda 4.7*](https://www.anaconda.com/why-we-removed-the-free-channel-in-conda-4-7/)

> One of the changes we made in Conda 4.7 was the removal of a software collection called “free” from the default channel configuration. The “free” channel is our collection of packages prior to the switch in recipes/compilers that we did for the Anaconda Distribution 5.0 release.

Solution: re-enable `free` channel.

1. Enable `free` channel **globally**.

   ```sh
   conda config --set restore_free_channel true
   conda install pyculib
   ```
2. Enable `free` channel for **current active environment** only.

   ```sh
   conda config --set restore_free_channel true --env
   conda install pyculib
   ```
3. **Temporary** use `free` channel in a single command.

   ```sh
   CONDA_RESTORE_FREE_CHANNEL=1 conda install pyculib
   ```

Answer (score 3):

#### Numba channel

Another option is to get this from the **numba** channel (they were the maintaining organization after all):

```
conda install -n my_env -c numba pyculib
```

The slight advantage to this is that Numba maintained `pyculib` out to NumPy 1.15, whereas the versions on the **anaconda** channel can at most run with NumPy 1.13.

As for CuPy, that is directly available on the **anaconda** channel and since it is actively maintained (unlike `pyculib`) you shouldn't need the **free** channel to access it.

Comment: Good solution for older pythons. However, if you're Py3.8 you'll get an error.

Comment: @not2qubit but Python 3.8 came out after the **free** channel deprecation, so it shouldn't even be an issue. Also, if working in Python 3.8, one should [switch to `CuPy` as the maintainers recommend](https://github.com/numba/pyculib#readme). The answers here are really more for running legacy code.